# How to keep select after jquery append

Tags: php, jquery

Ok guys here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wKbXx/24/

```
$(function() {
$( 'input[name=q1]' ).on( 'change', function() {
    var sel = $('[id^="comm"]'), opt = $( '<option/>' );
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        sel.append( $("<option />").val(this.value).text( this.id ) );
    } else {
        $('option[value=' + this.value + ']').remove();
    }
});
});
```

What I need to do is to select two colors with the check boxes. Let say red, and blue. Then using the select, Mark one red and one blue. Then check green. I want it to keep the selected data. Right now once you select green it wipes that data. How can I do that?

UPDATED TO REFLECT WORKING ANSWER.. UPDATED FIDDLE TOO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a slightly different approach; instead of always resetting the select boxes, I would check whether the text in the changed checkbox is already contained in the select boxes. If it is, I would assume it's been unchecked and remove the option from the select boxes. Otherwise I would append just that new option to the select boxes.

```
$(function() {
    $( 'input[name=q1]' ).on( 'change', function() {
        var sel = $('[id^="comm"]'), opt = $( '<option/>' );
        if (sel.find('option').text().indexOf(this.id) > 0) {
            $('option[value=' + this.value + ']').remove();
        } else {
            sel.append( $("<option />").val(this.value).text( this.id ) );
        }
    });
});
```

The downside with this version is that the order of the colors in the select boxes is determined by the order in which the checkboxes are clicked; with your version, the order of the colors in the select boxes is always the same as in the checkboxes.

(Hope that made sense.)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/0hLxzvh8/

Comment: Niffler, This worked, but I found in LARGE 1000+ entries the very first selection would always duplicate itself, and even when deleting ti would just add it.. but only the first one. 
Switching out how you did It I was able to fix the issue, I've put it as the good answer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the answer to your question...
You should have your rewrite on top as well.

```
$(function() {
    var sel = $('[id^="comm"]'), opt = $( '<option/>' );
    sel.html( opt.clone().text( '[Select One]' ) );

    $( 'input[name=q1]' ).on( 'change', function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            sel.append( $("<option />").val(this.value).text( this.id ) );
        }
        else {
            //Remove where ID matches up
            sel.children().remove();
        }

        if( sel.find( 'option' ).length > 1 ) {
           if( sel.find( 'option' ).length === 2 ) {
                sel.find( 'option' ).eq( 1 ).attr( 'selected',true );
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: this will only partially fix it. if you don't check to see what `option` values are already in the list in the for loop you will create dupes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the select box before you replace the options, then reset the value at the end.

```
$(function() {
$( 'input[name=q1]' ).on( 'change', function() {
    var sel = $('[id^="comm"]'), opt = $( '<option/>' );

    sel.each(function(){
        sel.data('previous', sel.val());
    });

    // overwrite the existing options
    sel.html( opt.clone().text( '[Select One]' ) );
    $( 'input[name=q1]:checked' ).each( function() {
        sel.append( $("<option />").val(this.value).text( this.id ) );
    }); 

    // if it had a value, set it back to that.
    if ( currentValue != '' ){
        sel.each(function(){
            sel.val(sel.data('previous'));
        });
    } else {   
        if( sel.find( 'option' ).length > 1 ) {
          if( sel.find( 'option' ).length === 2 ) {
                sel.find( 'option' ).eq( 1 ).attr( 'selected',true );
            }
        } 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This works for the first select box, but not the second. :( I'm looking to see how you did that and see if I can make it do that for the other selects as well.

Comment: use an `each()` and attach the value using `data()`

Comment: updated to use an each() to iterate the selects, then save and set the previous value using data().

Comment: double, while this works, its not keeping the data once you remove one of the selections.